# Action Requested: Android app child-directed treatment

Tags: google-play, admob

google play send an email to me about child-directed treatment

Dear App Developer,

We’re contacting you because Google has received a report that your Android app(s) and package name(s) listed below may be child-directed for the purposes of the Children’s Online Privacy Protection Act (COPPA). You can visit the Federal Trade Commission’s website to learn more about COPPA.

In 30 days, we will take the action to treat your app(s) listed below as primarily child-directed for applicable Google services that may appear in your app(s). For instance, this means AdMob will take steps to disable interest-based advertising and remarketing ads for your app(s).

If Google should NOT treat your app(s) as primarily child-directed (for example, because it is a mixed audience app), please complete the form(s) below by September 14, 2016.

.....

my app is about nursing and there are nursing questions in it... what should i do for change?

if i change the 3+ rating and make it 13+ ... everything will be OK ?

is there anyone who got a mail like this? before or now...

Comment: Ask google, not us

Comment: @KevinL genius! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Children's Online Privacy Protection Act is a United States law that prevents apps from collecting personal information from users who are known to be under 13 without verifiable parental consent.  I believe the problem is that AdMob is collecting information from your users, but you've rated the app for users under 13.

I believe you can fix this by either altering how AdMob serves your ads or changing the ratings.